# merge into matches woron

Tags: database, oracle

im trying to merge into a table.

this select doesnt find anything:

```
select * from dpr where dpr_qot_id=1111;
```

then i run this merge like the follwing:

```
MERGE INTO dpr d
USING (select dpr_ts, dpr_qot_id
         from dpr
        where dpr_qot_id = 1111
          and dpr_ts = to_date('30.11.1999', 'DD.MM.YYYY')) s
on (s.dpr_ts = d.dpr_ts and s.dpr_qot_id = d.dpr_qot_id)
when not matched then
  insert
    (DPR_TS,
     DPR_CLOSE,
     DPR_OPEN,
     DPR_HIGH,
     DPR_LOW,
     DPR_VOLUME,
     DPR_QOT_ID)
  values
    (to_date('30.11.2010', 'DD.MM.YYYY'),
     21.66,
     21.75,
     22.005,
     21.66,
     2556.00,
     1111)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
     set DPR_CLOSE  = 21.66,
         DPR_OPEN   = 21.75,
         DPR_HIGH   = 22.005,
         DPR_LOW    = 21.66,
         DPR_VOLUME = 2556.00;
```

and still this select doesn't find anything:

```
select * from dpr where dpr_qot_id=1111;
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you!

Greetings
Magda

Comment: Are you sure your merge is commited?

Comment: Feel free to open another question if you have an additional question.

Answer (score 3):

Since there are no dpr rows where dpr_qot_id=1111, the source (USING) query of your MATCH will also contain no rows, so there is no data to be merged - and so nothing is done.